# Convert to utf-8 - from email

Tags: php, email, encode

Im using Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3 to retrieve mail messages.

My subject on a mail is
Foo/æøå

`$message->getHeader('content-type')`
gives me `text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed`

Before any encoding my `$message->subject` looks like this

`Foo/µ°Õ - 2h - comment`

Then I try to do a iconv on the subject

`$message->subject = iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8', $message->subject);`

Now my subject looks like this

`Foo/├ª├©├Ñ - 2h - comment`

Which is not utf-8 :)

So what should I do?
I also tried with utf8_encode and mb_convert_encoding
but these gives the same result

Well I got it - but its a bit messy, but it works

```
$this->mails = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3(...);
$currentMessageId = $this->mails->getNumberByUniqueId($this->mails->getUniqueId($messageId));
$raw = $this->mails->getRawHeader($currentMessageId);
$l = explode("\n", $raw);
foreach($l AS $m) {
    if (strpos($m, 'Subject: ') === 0) {
        $subject = trim(str_replace('Subject: ', '', $m));
        break;
    }
}

$subject = str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($subject));
```

Comment: By the way right now im using Windows - but should be working on linux atleast

Comment: You should edit your post to mention that

Comment: Do you use mb_detect_encoding to be sure you are reading ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Where is the mail coming from?  It almost appears as if the email was sent with a different charset but did not specify the charset in the headers.

Comment: My mail is sent from thunderbird

Answer (score 3):

The `content-type`-field usually holds the encoding for the message body, not for the header. Can you have a look at the message in it's raw format? A field in ISO 8859-1 should look like this:

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Graphgr=F6=DFen?=
```

while an UTF8 encoded header should look like this:

```
=?UTF-8?B?w5xtbMOkdXRlIGluIFVURjg=?=
```

Comment: Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Foo/=E6=F8=E5_-_2h_-_comment?=